# Passing data from onReceive to new Activity

Tags: android

I've a notification bar, when I click on it, starts a new activity with same data (a string array). I have a problem passing data from onReceive.class to new Activity (Notify). When I click I see new activity but crashes with nullPointerE.

not1[x] is a array of string

My code

AlarmReceiver:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("com.example.myapp", null, context, Notify.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notify", not1[x]);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Notify:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
      if (b != null) {
          Intent intent = getIntent();
          String[] notify2 = b.getStringArray("notify");

          textView1.setText("notify2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String[] getArray=getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("notify");
```

In between not1[x] is a string not an array.

```
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;

mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.somepngfile,"some text",System.currentTimeMillis());


       Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "title";
        CharSequence contentText = "ontent";
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(thisclass.this,nextclass.class);

        notifyIntent.putExtra("Value", finalresponse[1]+","+finalresponse[2]+","+finalresponse[3]);



        PendingIntent intent = 
            PendingIntent.getActivity(BackService.this, 0, 
            notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
        notifyDetails.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notifyDetails.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notifyDetails.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notifyDetails.defaults|= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

In next class

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
        i.getStringExtra("Value");

        String[] response=i.getStringExtra("Value").split(",");
```

Comment: let me make whole program for you

Answer (score 0):

Is this `not1[x]` a String Array? It looks like an element of a String Array that is actually a String.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace below code in **AlarmReceiver** class. its works for me...

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

if we use 0 instead of **PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT** flag, on the Receiver side i.e getIntent().getExtras() not update the data dynamically, assign 1st passed data every time....